# It is possible to combine date and time and stored into datetime format

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

Here what I am trying

```
CREATE TABLE #date (dt datetime)    
declare @date Date ='2019-01-29',
        @time time='11:06:31.095',

INSERT INTO #date
    SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR,CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@date)+' '+CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@time))
```

It gives error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server allows you to add `datetime` values, so you can do:

```
select convert(datetime, @date) + convert(datetime, @time)
```

Comment: It is so fast!:)

Comment: when i converted time then there are 2 ms difference .

Comment: My actual time is "11:06:31.095" and the time stored in table is "11:06:31.097"

Comment: @Thebeginner . . . `datetime` is not accurate to milliseconds (it is accurate to about 3 milliseconds).  You may want `datetime2` instead.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, is there possible way to stored same time in table?

Comment: @Thebeginner . . . Just use `datetime2` instead of `datetime`.

Comment: @Thebeginner The precision of `datetime` is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#rounding-of-datetime-fractional-second-precision).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
CREATE TABLE #date (dt datetime)

declare @date Date ='2019-01-29' 
declare @time time='11:06:31.095' 

INSERT INTO #date 
    SELECT CONVERT(datetime,@date)+ CONVERT(datetime,@time)

select * from #date
```

Comment: when i converted time then there are 2 ms difference,My actual time is "11:06:31.095" and the time stored in table is "11:06:31.097"

Comment: @Thebeginner You can do it using datatype datetime2(3) but it is not possible with concatenating and preserving that values in millisecond.